# The difference between these two sentences

Tags: sentence-meaning

"Sheep eat grass"
or
"sheep eat grasses

Which one is more appropriate?
I do not think that the word grass is an uncountable noun

Answer (score 1):

As there are different kinds of grass, plural **grasses** in the proper context could be valid.

> This pasture has a variety of grasses growing in it, a couple of which are quite bitter, imparting an off taste to the milk.

Absent context, there's no way to know which one is "more appropriate".  But simple universal truths typically use the singular:

> Cows eat *grass*.
>
> Vegans don't eat *meat*.